# Encoding inputs to ASCII from form submission by adding increment

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, ascii

How would I code some JS in order to loop a string of characters through an ASCII table and yield a shifted string of characters?

For example:
In the first label on the form we submit an increment = '2'
and in the second label on the form we submit = 'abcd'
I would like this to happen:
"abcd" => [97,98,99,100] => [97+2,98+2,99+2,100+2] => [99,100,101,102] => "cdef"

Final result 'cdef'

I know I would have to use .charCodeAt() at some point and a loop. But I just don't know where to start!

Comment: What will you do with z?

Comment: z would be moved on to a again using a modulo % operation

Comment: What you're looking for is a [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). You can just search for JavaScript implementations of it like [this](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/caesar-cipher-javascript) for example.

Comment: sir, thank you so much!!! finally a lead